# How to get the values that are in ng-model, which comes from a select in angularjs1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I created a select, where I get a person and their values. But when I try to pass these values on ng-model this is giving undefined.

in html.

```
<ion-view view-title="Cadastro Livro Preto">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">

        </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>

              <div class="list card">
                <select ng-model="cadLivroPreto" ng-options="y.nome for (x, y) in linkPessoasLoja">
                </select>
                  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                    <h3 ng-model=cadLivroPreto.nome>Nome: {{cadLivroPreto.nome}}</h3><br/>
                  </label>
                  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                    <h3 ng-model="cadLivroPreto.cpf">CPF: {{cadLivroPreto.cpf}}</h3><br/>
                  </label>
              </div>  

                <h3>teste: {{cadLivroPreto.id}}</h3><br/>
                <h3>teste: {{cadLivroPreto.nome}}</h3><br/> 
        <!-- 
        Acrescentar telefone
      -->

    </div>
    <button class = "button button-block button-dark" ng-click="Cadastrar()"> Cadastrar</button>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

in my controller.js

```
$scope.cadLivroPreto = {};

   //$scope.pessoa = {};

   $scope.Cadastrar = function(){

          console.log($scope.cadLivroPreto.nome);
          console.log($scope.cadLivroPreto.cpf);


  };
```

In the html what is in the expression {{}} I can see on the screen, but when I try to give console.log the same putting it in the ng-model in the controller is appearing undefined.

Can anybody help me ? I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just check once what is coming inside $scope.cadLivroPreto. whether it is a value or object

Comment: Did you already tried adding a binding expression (es: {{cadLivroPreto | json}} ) just before the select element in the html in order to check this is not a scope issue?

Comment: When I put only cadLibroPreto in html like this: <h3> test: {{cadLivroPreto}} </ h3> <br/>, I see my json complete. But when I do this in the controller like this: console.log ($ scope.cadLibrary); I have this result: {$$ hashKey: "object: 62"} @RakeshBurbure

Comment: No I have not tried it yet, how do I do it? @SPArchaeologist

Comment: I'm trying to create something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select_object_y  But I need to get the values that will come from select.@RakeshBurbure and @SPArchaeologist

Comment: that was my point. In the example, they output the current value of the selected item to a "label" just after the "you selected" message. That way, you can check that the select control is setting the value to the model. You seem to only check for the value in the controller. I was basically suggesting that maybe for some reason the select is in an isolated scope and therefore the model get set on that isolated scope instead of the one you are checking in the controller.

Comment: since you stated that  <h3> test: {{cadLivroPreto}} </ h3> <br/> shows the actual expected value, my logical conclusion is that the model gets set on a different scope from the one your controller uses. I am not an Ionic expert... but maybe it is creating an isolated scope somewhere?

Comment: I changed one thing in select and I was able to get the json line that I'm picking up in the select, but I'm not able to do foreach to get the value of each of json. On the ionic it is based on the angularjs and knowing how to implement the angularjs and ionic works.@SPArchaeologist

Comment: My select is like this now: <select ng-model = "cadLivroPreto.linkPessoasLojas" ng-options = "linkPeopleLibs.name for linkPeopleLinks in linkPeopleLoja">
                </ select> This way I can get an array of json that is in a list. When I get this in the controller it's like this: {id: "1", name: "Lucas test", cpf: "40056682832", cim: "lucas test", cell phone: "997306213", ...} I got this json from that json: console.log ($ scope.cadLivroPreto.linkPessoasLojas); @SPArchaeologist

Comment: But my problem now is how I can pass a foreach on this variable $ scope.cadLivroPreto.linkPessoasLojas, I'm trying to pass the foreach to get the values ​​that are coming from json. Do you know how I can do this?@SPArchaeologist

Comment: I tried to do the foreach like this: $ scope.cadLivroPreto.linkPessoasLojas.forEach (function (element, index, array) {
                  //element.id = element.id;
                  element.name = element.name;
                  element.id = element.id;
                  $ scope.name = element.name;
                  console.log (element.id);
                  console.log (element.name);
        }) But it does not work. @SPArchaeologist